# Regular expression to split on Hebrew letters

Tags: java, regex, hebrew

I'm trying to figure out what would be the regular expression to split a Hebrew word so I'll get an array of letters/numbers/symbols in that word.

I don't know Hebrew but this what I have now (used with `java.util.regex.Pattern.find` on each word):

`(?:(?:\p{L}+|\p{N}+)[^\p{L}\p{N}]*|[^\p{L}\p{N}]+)`

As the text I'm using the Genesis Book of the Holy Bible (`Genesis.xml` from http://www.tanach.us/Pages/Technical.html#Offline).

**UPDATE**

I've changed regex to a much simpler which seems to be working fine.

`\p{L}[^\p{L}]*`

However if someone knows Hebrew and can tell that this is a correct approach or not that would be helpful.

For example:

Input:

```
בְּ/רֵאשִׁ֖ית
בָּרָ֣א
אֱלֹהִ֑ים
אֵ֥ת
הַ/שָּׁמַ֖יִם
וְ/אֵ֥ת
הָ/אָֽרֶץ׃
```

Output:

```
"בְּ/"
"רֵ"
"א"
"שִׁ֖"
"י"
"ת"
"בָּ"
"רָ֣"
"א"
"אֱ"
"לֹ"
"הִ֑"
"י"
"ם"
"אֵ֥"
"ת"
"הַ/"
"שָּׁ"
"מַ֖"
"יִ"
"ם"
"וְ/"
"אֵ֥"
"ת"
"הָ/"
"אָֽ"
"רֶ"
"ץ׃"
```

Comment: which lang actaully you're running?

Comment: I don't see a `Genesis.xml` listed at the page you linked to. Perhaps you could simply present a list of a few words that are and/or a few words that aren't properly splitting here?

Comment: Which language is this? Python `re` module does not support `\p`, you need to use the `regex` package.

Comment: Can you use octal ranges, something like those found here http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/hebrew.html like `[\340-\372]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Java. I'm removing the Python tag.

Comment: @JonathanEunice - It is a download, http://www.tanach.us/Tanach.zip

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - Thanks for suggestion. I removed Python tag.

Comment: @cfqueryparam - This seems useful, thanks.

Comment: @ruakh - Right, corrected.

Comment: Could you explain how you want to split on the hebrew letters? For example, shalom (שָׁלוֹם); what you expect the result of your split to be?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use this pattern:

```
String[] allWords = doc.split("[^א-ת']+");
```

Try to change the order of the hewbrew letters, first the Alef and then the Tav